# jQuery calculation total

Tags: jquery

I'd need a little help with a jQuery script.
So here it is:

HTML:

```
    1<input type="text" name="plastvaike_v" id="plastvaike_v" /><br />
2<input type="text" name="plastsuur_v" id="plastsuur_v" /><br />
3<input type="text" name="klaas_v" id="klaas_v" /><br />
4<input type="text" name="plekk_v" id="plekk_v" /><br /><br />
<span id="plastvaike_t">0.00</span> + <span id="plastsuur_t">0.00</span> + <span id="klaas_t">0.00</span> + <span id="plekk_t">0.00</span> = <span id="total">0.00</span>
```

JS:

```
$('#plastvaike_v').keyup(function(ev){
    var plastvaike_t = $('#plastvaike_v').val() * 0.04;
    $('#plastvaike_t').html((plastvaike_t).toFixed(2));
});
$('#plastsuur_v').keyup(function(ev){
    var plastsuur_t = $('#plastsuur_v').val() * 0.08;
    $('#plastsuur_t').html((plastsuur_t).toFixed(2));
})
$('#klaas_v').keyup(function(ev){
    var klaas_t = $('#klaas_v').val() * 0.08;
    $('#klaas_t').html((klaas_t).toFixed(2));
})
$('#plekk_v').keyup(function(ev){
    var plekk_t = $('#plekk_v').val() * 0.08;
    $('#plekk_t').html((plekk_t).toFixed(2));
});
```

And a working demo in JsFiddle you can find [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HrElmo/yyhNY/)

Now the thing i need, that i need to display total value after "=". That has to be done in jQuery.

And it would be nice if someone could tell how to make numbers appear after i write any number in text box. Right now there is 0.00. Even if i delete them, the "+" will be still there.
Hope you understand what i tried to say .. my main language isn't english.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say, "And it would be nice if someone could tell how to make numbers appear after i write any number in text box. Right now there is 0.00. Even if i delete them, the '+' will be still there." Can you explain a little more?

Comment: I don't know how to explain it now. As you can see, i have there <span id="plastvaike_t">0.00</span> + ... The thing i'd like to have instead of that, is that if i write a number in first text box, named plastvaike_v, it will show the result, now if i fill another text box, named plastsuur_v, it will show for example "0.64 + 0.32 = 0.96" and so on. So, if only one text box is filled, it will only show one result, there will be no ".. + 0.00 + 0.00 = .."

Comment: I updated mine to work better. I've got to run, but that almost does what you want (only the = sign is showing). http://jsfiddle.net/yyhNY/7/

Comment: Thank you very much. The = sign isn't big problem, but if you have time later and it isn't so hard to remove it, you could try. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good start (http://jsfiddle.net/yyhNY/7/):

```
function updateView() {
    var plastvaike_t = $('#plastvaike_v').val() * 0.04,
        plastsuur_t = $('#plastsuur_v').val() * 0.08,
        klaas_t = $('#klaas_v').val() * 0.08,
        plekk_t = $('#plekk_v').val() * 0.08;

    // Take all the numbers as an array, and get rid of the ones that are 0.
    var operands = [plastvaike_t, plastsuur_t, klaas_t, plekk_t];
    for (var i = 0; i < operands.length; i++) {
        if (operands[i] == 0)
            operands.splice(i--, 1);
    }

    // join puts them all together with a + separating them
    $('#operands').text(operands.join(' + '));

    // This sum method is something you'll either have to add to the array
    // prototype or write yourself—it's not part of javascript.
    var total = operands.sum();
    $('#total').text(total.toFixed(2));

    if (total == 0) $('#total').hide();
    else $('#total').show();
}

$('#plastvaike_v, #plastsuur_v, #klaas_v, #plekk_v').keyup(updateView);
```

Comment: might want to add check for `NAN`

Comment: I agree it will be important to deal with non-number input, but I think I'll let the OP deal with that or ask another question when he runs into problems; this answer helps him figure out the specific issue he asked about. (Any disagreement? I'll expand the answer to help him deal with that too if that's the right thing to do.)

Comment: agree..just throwing it out there as much for OP as anyone else. Fairly simple however to add a helper function

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$('#plastvaike_v').val() * 0.04;
```

try

```
parseInt($('#plastvaike_v').val(), 10) * 0.04;
```

I think the problem right now is that Jquery tries to multiply a string with an Integer and that is why you get 0.0.

Comment: Always use the `base` parameter in `parseInt`! `parseInt($('#plastvaike_v').val(), 10)` Otherwise values like `015` will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To easily handle the "+" operator removal on empty value entered, you could simply consider the left part of your equality as a unique span instead of four, and dynamically setting its text as an array that you fill with not empty and only number values and from which you call method "join" with the unique argument being " + ".

Moreover, you may not forget to optimize a little by using closure variables to refer to your inputs and spans.

And finally, you may note that if your inputs are inside a form, the form's DOM element directly refers its named inputs as live properties : suppose a form named myForm with an input named myInput, then your input is accessible via document.getElementById("myForm").myInput which is so much faster than using jQuery to get it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done quite concisely without the need for ids, as follows :

HTML :

```
<div id="foo">
    1<input type="text" name="plastvaike_v" data-factor="0.04" /><br />
    2<input type="text" name="plastsuur_v" data-factor="0.08" /><br />
    3<input type="text" name="klaas_v" data-factor="0.08" /><br />
    4<input type="text" name="plekk_v" data-factor="0.08" /><br /><br />
<span>0.00</span> + <span>0.00</span> + <span>0.00</span> + <span>0.00</span> = <span>0.00</span>
</div>
```

`#foo` is just a means of selecting the inputs and spans. You could select them by other means, eg by class - as long as they are selectable as groups.

JavaScript :

```
var $spans = $("#foo span");
var $inputs = $("#foo input").on('keyup', function() {
    var total = 0;
    $inputs.each(function(i, input) {
        var val = (Number(input.value) * Number($(input).data('factor'))) || 0;
        $spans.eq(i).text(val.toFixed(2));
        total += val;
    });
    $spans.filter(":last")text(total.toFixed(2));
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ry6rM/)**

Of course, you can keep the ids if you need them for other purposes.